# Show that frac(1/x) is a measure-preserving transformation

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

Let $X=[0,1)$, $\tau(x)=<\frac{1}{x}>$ (the fractional part of 1/x) for $x \neq 0$ and $\tau(0)=0$. Let $d\mu = \frac{dx}{\log2 (1+x)}$. Show that $\tau$ is a measure-preserving transformation.

$\textit{Work so far:}$

To show that $\tau$ is a measure-preserving transformation of $X$, we need to show that

(i) $\tau^{-1}(E)$ is measurable whenever $E$ is measurable

(ii) $\mu(\tau^{-1}(E)) = \mu(E)$ for any measurable $E \subseteq X$

For (i) we have a few different characterizations for measurable $E$. The one I tried working with was that $E$ is measurable iff $E$ is almost an $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$ set. If $E$ is, say, almost $G_\delta$, then we can write
$$E = G \cup Z$$
where $G$ is a $G_\delta$ set and $Z$ is a set of measure zero. In which case,
$$ \tau^{-1}(E) = \tau^{-1}(G \cup Z) = \tau^{-1}(G) \cup \tau^{-1}(Z)$$
...but I'm not sure how to show that $\tau^{-1}(G)$ and $\tau^{-1}(Z)$ are measurable given how $\tau$ is defined.

For (ii), if we assume that $E$ is measurable then
$$\mu(\tau^{-1}(E)) = \int_{\tau^{-1}(E)} 1 d\mu= \int_X \chi_{\tau^{-1}(E)}d\mu = \int_X \chi_E(\tau(x)) d\mu  $$
$$=\int_E <\frac{1}{x}> \frac{1}{\log 2} \frac{dx}{1+x}$$
Since $<\frac{1}{x}> \leq 1$ then by monotinicity of the Lebesgue integral,
$$\cdots \leq \int_E \frac{1}{\log 2} \frac{dx}{1+x} = \mu(E)$$
How might we show "$\geq$"?

There is also a hint given:
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(x+k)(x+k+1)} = \frac{1}{1+x}$$
...but it has not yet proven useful.

This is problem 8 in chapter 6 of "Real Analysis" by Stein and Shakarchi. I'm trying to do this problem along with #10 so that I can better understand the connection between measure and continued fractions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Hints: It suffices to look at intervals $I$ as the generate the Borel sets
(and you show easily that $\tau^{-1} I$ is a union of intervals, whence measurable). For the second you need to integrate over these inverse images of $I$. For this note that 
$$ \tau^{-1} (y) =\{\frac{1}{n+y} : n\geq 1\}$$
and use this to carry out the integrals. You should arrive at the above-mentioned telescopic sum.

Comment: You just pipped me to submitting my answer - an extra hint for the OP is to use the Hahn-Kolmagrov Extension Theorem and to check the preimage of cyclinder sets. (It's a neater way of doing the algebra!)

Comment: Does it suffice to just look at intervals? I believe the intervals generate the Borel sets, but there are plenty of sets which are Lebesgue measurable, yet not Borel.

Comment: @DanielLautzenheiser  I tend to stick to Borel for simplicity. But true it has its limitations.